# How to append something right before the closing </head> tag using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I tried this but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
$('</head>').appendTo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the item you're trying to append isn't valid HTML, it's simply the closing head tag and presumably already exists in the document.  Second, you shouldn't be using `appendTo` in this case, but rather `append`:

```
$('head').append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>");
```

Third, there's no reason to do either because you could just as easily change the location using javascript as well.

```
window.location = "http://google.com";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it RIGHT before the end of the head tag: (as the question states)

1. Get the head tag
2. Find the last item
3. Insert after that last item.

$("head").find(":last").after("<meta stuff='stuff'>");

Answer (score 1):

What is your actual goal?  Do you just want to send the user to google?

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/";
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `append` only works reliably within the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('head').append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>");
```

Comment: I think you should use `'head'` not `'<head>'`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('head').append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this instead:

```
$('head').append("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>");
```

Proper use for `.appendTo()` would be the reverse:

```
$("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://google.com'>").appendTo('head');
```