# Add Open Graph Meta Tag After Page is Loaded, for Facebook Share button

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I have to assign a thumbnail to the page:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/example.png" />
```

However, as the site is a WordPress site, the information of thumbnail is loaded when body is loaded (it is a WordPress page). Therefore, I use the following JS to add the tag (inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467347/how-to-append-something-right-before-the-closing-head-tag-using-jquery)):

```
<script>
$('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/example.png" />');
</script>
```

The tag is successfully added to `<head>`, but the thumbnail does not display after I click Facebook Share button. Is it true that the Facebook button only evaluate the original source code, instead of the modified source code?

If Yes, what can I do to make Facebook Share button's thumbnail appearing ?

FYI, here is the Facebook share button code:

```
<fb:share-button type="button_count" href="http://example.com"></fb:share-button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, since JS code does not get executed. See [How does Facebook Sharer select Images and other metadata when sharing my URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138460/how-does-facebook-sharer-select-images)

> **Can I update these meta tags with client side code like Javascript or jQuery?** No. Much like search engine crawlers, the Facebook
>   scraper does not execute scripts so whatever meta tags are present
>   when the page is downloaded are the meta tags that are used for image
>   selection.